# Как передать в ссылку на фото счетчик цикла?

Tags: html, django

**Нужно, чтобы в итоге на странице появилось 2 фотографии.**

Адрес фотографий:

news/static/news/image/1.jpg

news/static/news/image/2.jpg

---

*код HTML*

```
{% load static%}

{% block content %}
  {% for post in object_list %}
    {% with y=forloop.counter|stringformat:"s" %}
    {% with template="news/image/"|add:y|add:".jpg" %}
    <img src="{% static '{{template}}' %}" class="rounded float-left" width="70px" alt="{{template}}">
    {% endwith %}
    {% endwith %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Но вместо фото выводит иконку картинки(типо не загрузилось) и текст news/image/1.jpg и ...2.jpg для второго.
Т.е. адрес правильный, есть и в urlspatterns строчка  `+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)`. В `objects_list` точно ровно 2 элемента

Если нельзя так делать, как я это сделала, то напишите, пожалуйста, как можно передать счетчик цикла в адрес фото

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуй вынести `{{template}}` за `{% static %}`

```
 <img src="{% static '' %}{{template}}" class="rounded float-left" width="70px" alt="{{template}}">
```